# very small div alignment with hover doesn't work

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to get small divs (5px by 5px) next to each other with 1px white between them and when I hover over one div, they must be highlighted. But when there is a div below it, the hover function doesn't work in Chrome. It does in IE.

But in IE, I don't have a 1px white around each div.

Maybe I've got the complete code wrong :-(

http://jsfiddle.net/00a4n9cp/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

.bb {
background-color: blue;
display: inline-block;
width: 5px;
height: 5px;
color: white;
margin-right: 1px;
margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.bb:hover{
background-color: red;
}

.aa{
background-color: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
height: 20px;
top:  0px;
margin-top: -5px;
display: block;
line-height: 0.1em;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="aa">
<div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div><div class="bb"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem you have is of `font-size` and appropriate `line-height`. Nothing else. Need to reset those. This is because, floats are removed from the normal document flow allowing other elements to flow around them wheras inline-blocks stay in the document flow.

That's it.

Just add `font-size: 0px;` to your `.aa` and `line-height: 5px;` to your `.bb`.

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/m4mLz4qL/1/***

*Complete CSS*:

```
.bb {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px; line-height: 5px;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.bb:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
.aa {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works too, I guess a float is not needed because of the inline-block?

Comment: Yes. `floating` is not required. These two articles will explain the difference in detail: (1) http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block and (2) http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/

Comment: Great! Gonna check it out

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.bb {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:-4px;
}
```

to

```
.bb {
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

Make sure you clear floats after all .bb divs.

[**See updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/00a4n9cp/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS class..

```
.bb {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 1px;
     float:left;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

With this you can hover see in chrome too

Comment: With this you can hover see in also chrome